# Show message if post title empty when attempting to publish

Tags: wordpress

How can I show a message if someone tries to publish a post with no title?
When I click on Add New Post and submit with an empty title, the post is added. According to the client, there should be a restriction for the empty title.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#publish').on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery('#title').val().length === 0 ) {
        jQuery('#title').css('border','2px solid #a00');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13749481)

Comment: Conversation start from top.